# I am confused when to use instrumentation test and when to use unit test

Tags: android, unit-testing, testing, robolectric, androidx-test

With AndroidX Test Framework now we can run Espresso test as unit test using Robolectric backend . But am confused when to use instrumentation test and when to use unit test.

Let's say we've two screens, **MovieListActivity** and **MovieDetailActivity**. when I click on an item in the **MovieListActivity**, details of that movie will be shown in the **MovieDetailActivity**.

Now with this scenario, what could be the possible unit tests and what could be the possible instrumentation tests?

For example, I can write instrumentation test to

- Check if the movies are listed
- Clicking on the movie goes to detail screen
- Detail screen displays the details correctly.

but now, these tests can be run as unit tests too, (since we're using Android X Test Framework) plus it's faster, as we're not running the test in a device/emulator. So what makes a test eligible for the instrumentation test?

What if I want to run a test as both unit test and instrumentation test?

As we're using Android X Test Framework the same unit test file can be run as an instrumentation test by copying the file to `androidTest` folder. This makes duplicate file and makes the test case maintenance hard. (For example if I make an edit in the unit `test` folder, the same modification should be done in `androidTest` file.)

- Is there any way I can mark a test to run as both instrumentation test and unit test?
- If it's a bad practice, what's the best practice and what are other best practices should be
  considered when using Android X Test Framework?

Comment: The simple answer: you use unit tests whenever no need to use android APIs, but when you need to use android APIs like manipulating activity, widgets, stuff like `TextView`, `EditText`.. you've to use instrumental tests under `androidTest` package

Comment: @Zain simple and concise answer!

Comment: @Zain Yeah that makes sense, but what am asking is, when it comes to `AndroidX Test Framework` with `Robolectric`,  on what basis the test type should be chosen?

Answer (score 4):

I use a basic strategy where I use, `Android X Test | Robolectric` for writing unit test that needs `context`, like all the new jetpack component are very tightly coupled with the framework we need context to work with them, so `Robolectric` will work great, no need for `androidTest Instrumentation` but if I'm working with Views that needs me to check `set` feature of a view and make it visible on my ui with some fancy animation or custom thing I use espresso Instrumentation.

I'm not getting into details but I will be creating a supporting blog for the explanation, but Hackish Cheatsheet of Test and Framework IMO would be

```
Remote DataSource Testing [Retrofit] - Mockserver | Fakes | Mocks
Local DataSource database [Room] - Android X Test | Robolectric 
Local DataSource Prefs [SharedPrefernces] - Android X Test | Robolectric 
Local DataSource Store [DataSource] - Android X Test | Robolectric 
Repository Layer | UseCases | business-logic  - JUnit 4/5 | Fakes | Mocks
ViewModel & LiveData - Android X Test | Robolectric 
Navigation [Navhost|Intents] - Android X Test | Robolectric 
View & Animations [Activity|Fragments|CustomViews] - Espresso|Barista Instrumentation
Notifications Test - Instrumentation and ADB
Broadcast Test - Instrumentation and ADB
Content provider - Instrumentation and ADB
Firebase Testing(depends on things you are testing) - Espresso|Barista Instrumentation | Android X Test | Robolectric | ADB
```

Do let me know if you have separate experince.

Comment: the cheatsheet is very helpful